# Find the sum of values of within a subcategory in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The given employee Table has multiple columns, including Departments with 10 different departments and a salary column with 3 values: low,medium and high. How to find How many employees of each salary range are present in different departments?

The concerned excel sheet has 14999 entries, this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGJEQ.jpg
shows how the table is formatted

Comment: Can you post an example of your input, your code and your output please? Currently, it is very difficult for anyone to help you

Comment: Hi dan71995: please help us help you by providing the code you already have and the error you get when running it.

Comment: Maybe you can read about this function: [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I'm new to programming and stackoverflow in general. Ive updated the post with the data

Comment: I'm not downloading some link off of mediafire to answer the question.  Please include a [mcve] in your question

Comment: This sounds like an exercise, not like a problem you are facing. Please check how to make a question [ask]

Comment: Once again i apologize for my mistakes, im learning python from online resources and i found this sample database, i was able to find the cumulative salaries across departments but i dont know how to use multiple arguments in python

Comment: @dan71995: Check the answer below: Let me know it solves your problem or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

Sample df:

```
import pandas as pd
Dept = ['AA','BB','CC','AA','CC']
Sal = ['Low', 'Low', 'High', 'High', 'High']


df = pd.DataFrame(data = list(zip(Dept,Sal)), \
                  columns=['Dept','Sal'])
```

Code to get the count of salary per dept

```
df[['Dept', 'Sal']].groupby(['Dept', 'Sal']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul for the answer, it is close but doesn't output the  exact solution. After trial and error I've found the solution                                                                                             dept_sal = HR[['department', 'salary']].groupby(['department', 'salary']).size().reset_index()
dept_sal.columns = ['department', 'salary', 'count']
dept_sal

Comment: Glad you worked it out after the help!!